# How to use an array to store scores per round

Tags: swift

I want to create a new array programmatically every round to store that rounds scores. So say I have

```
var roundNumber = 3
var team1Score = 5
var team2Score = 7
```

And I would store these in array

```
var scores = [Int]()

scores.append(team1Score)
scores.append(team2Score)
print (scores)
```

How would I dynamically change the name and then store the scores from that round so that I can load them at a later time. Or store that array into another array and create a new one so I can call upon it later and fill the new array with the current rounds scores without typing out every new array?

Comment: It sounds like you should start creating classes and structs. Storing the scores of both teams in the same array while certainly cause problems and will be hard to understand in the future. Why not create a `Round` class which holds the score for both teams at the same time and store an array of `Round`s?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "How would I dynamically change the name"? The name of what? Definately sounds like you need an array of structs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use array of structs, something like below

```
struct Result {
    let round: Int
    let team1Score: Int
    let team2Score: Int
}

var results = [Result]()

// round 1
let result = Result(round: 1, team1Score: 7, team2Score: 5)
results.append(result)

// round N or maybe could be done in loop
let resultN = Result(round: 2, team1Score: 17, team2Score: 10)
results.append(resultN)
```

Comment: When you say 'or maybe could be done in a loop' do you know how you would go about doing this. Create the array called result+(RoundNumber) so have the roundNumber += 1 when you hit 'next round' and then label the array accordingly?

Comment: Okay so I created a func called `roundCall()` which does this `roundCall = "results" + String(RoundNumber)` is there a way to create a new array using the data from this var roundCall?

Answer (score 0):

```
class ScoreCard{
    var round:Int?
    var player1Score:Int?
    var player2Score:Int?
}
var s = [ScoreCard]()
let scoreCard = ScoreCard()
scoreCard.round = 1
scoreCard.player1Score = 10
scoreCard.player2Score = 20
s.append(scoreCard)
```

This will do the job I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary and tuples for what you seem to be after.
Store the score of each round in a tuple:

```
var round1 = (team1score: 1, team2score: 3)
```

Then create a dictionary (dict) to store the tuple with the name you associated with it:

```
var scores: [String: (team1score: Int, team2score: Int)] = [:]
scores["1"] = round1

var anotherRound = (team1score: 12, team2score: 32)
scores["some round"] = anotherRound

print (scores)
```

You can define the dictionary to use the number of the round as the key, if that is what you need. Then the code would look like:

```
var round1 = (team1score: 1, team2score: 3)
var scores: [Int: (team1score: Int, team2score: Int)] = [:]
scores[1] = round1

var anotherRound = (team1score: 12, team2score: 32)
scores[4] = anotherRound

print (scores)
```

For doing stuff with the scores data, you can iterate easily:

```
for (round, score) in scores {
    print("round \(round) had winner score \(max(score.team1score,score.team2score))")
}
```